# how to write sql query for select statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$dep=$_SESSION['dep'];
$type="DON’T DO’S";
$res=  mysql_query("select * from treatment where treatment_dep='$dep' and treatment_type='$type'");
while($res1=  mysql_fetch_array($res)){ 
    echo $res1['treatment_treatment'];
}
```

This query is working only if i remove "and treatment_type='$type'" from the query . This is because $type contains single quotes.

How to write query to resolve this type of problem.

Comment: It would be best to convert to an API that has parametrized queries. Failing that, use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated. Please either use mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: Those aren't single quotes, they're "smart quotes". They shouldn't cause a problem, but real single quotes would.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I got the output .. :)

Answer (score -1):

This will help you to check the error.

```
   // Perform Query
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    // Check result
    // This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
    if (!$result) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
        die($message);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$dep=$_SESSION['dep'];
$type="DON’T DO’S";

//Sanitize it for SQL as follows
$type = str_replace("'", "''", trim($type));
//Sanitization Complete

$res=  mysql_query("select * from treatment where treatment_dep='$dep' and treatment_type='$type'");
while($res1=  mysql_fetch_array($res)){ 
    echo $res1['treatment_treatment'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing quote characters to \' in your variable, like this:

```
$type = "DON\'T DO\'S";
```

If you would need to do this for dynamic data, you could use

```
$type = strtr($type, "'", "\'");
```